# Grav CMS adding localization via admin

Tags: grav

I am using the admin plugin. I can create a page fine, and it uses the language I have selected as my locale as the language of page, which is also fine. But I can't add a different localization for the page unless I manually add one in the filesystem. When I add one in the filesystem, I get a nice drop down selecting the locale of the same page. However, without manually creating a localized file in the filesystem, I can't create a different version of the same page.

Is there a way to do this in the admin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the page you want to save/duplicate as another language, the drop down for the save button has the options.

[image]